# adding mulltiple items to Slick grid with knockout observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, slickgrid, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray

I am using a knockout custom bindingHandler to bind data to slickgrid based on an example by rniemeyer, when the code runs if you click the "add" link then a row is added to the grid using myObservableArray.push(newRow), however when you try to replace all the data in the grid via the "replace" link the grid is not updated and the add button stops working. I'm trying to update the obsevable array by calling myObservableArray(multipleRows) is this the correct way of doing it?

The Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/bwSmy/

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([]),
    addItem: function() {
        this.items.push(new Item(0, "New", 5.00));  // works
    },
    replace: function() {
        var newList = [new Item(0, "New", 6.00),new Item(0, "New", 7.00)]
        this.items(newList); // fails without throwing error
    }, 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the SetData in the update of the knockout custom binding.
 grid.setData(data,true);

here's what it would look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slickGrid = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var settings = valueAccessor();
        var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.data);
        var columns = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.columns);
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.options) || {};
        grid = new Slick.Grid(element, data, columns, options);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, viewModel) {
        var settings = valueAccessor();
        var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.data); //just for subscription
        grid.resizeCanvas(); // NB Very important for when a scrollbar appears        
        grid.setData(data,true); // This is what was missing
        grid.render();
    }
}
```

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/joybroto/bwSmy/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Knockout but I'd imagine it would need to look like this:

```
var newList = [new Item(0, "New", 6.00),new Item(0, "New", 7.00)];
this.items(ko.observableArray(newList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout and SlickGrid use underlying data array to perform their work. All you need to do is to keep them use the same array.
By

```
this.items(newList);
```

you make Knockout use other array. Good opton here is to ask SlickGrid to do the same:

```
grid.setData(newList, true);
grid.render();
```

here is http://jsfiddle.net/bwSmy/6/ to see other options